# How can I ignore a child element's margins?

Tags: android, android-layout

#### Background

I'm developing a custom notification layout by injecting an OS-generated notification view into my own layout. My layout must be as short as possible, which is `50dp` in Android 10.

#### Problem

The view that I'm injecting into my view has margins that cause it to stretch my layout from `50dp` to `66dp`.

#### Code

The following layout is a simplification of what's going on to demonstrate the problem:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/full_height_view"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Note that `container` has `minHeight` of 50dp, which I don't want to be exceeded. The problem is the margins from `bad_view` sum up to 66dp and stretch the parent to 66dp.

#### Question

How can I prevent the margins on `bad_view` from stretching the parent beyond its minimum height? I cannot set a fixed height on the parent because the exact height is OS-dependent. And I cannot modify `bad_view` because it's generated by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by setting the visibility of `bad_view` to `gone`.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution: use `GridLayout` vertical weights to override the problematic view's height. This gave me the flexibility of a weighted horizontal `LinearLayout` but with the addition of vertical weights.